# Performance optimization of queries using LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-performance, sql-limit

I have a table, `files` partitioned into 100 tables - by the `user_id` (hash partitioning). Each table has between 1-2 million rows.

I am trying to get a file based on the file id and the user id. The columns are indexed. When I do this:

```
select * from files where file_id=124 and user_id=456;
```

The query takes around 200 ms

Knowing that there could be only 1 file per id, if I do this

```
select * from files where file_id=124 and user_id=456 LIMIT 1;
```

*The query is 10 times faster*, taking only around 20ms. I tried this for multiple file id's, and the results are more or less similar.

So my questions here are:

1. Is it faster, as it then stops when it gets the record it is looking for - and doesn't have to scan all 100 tables?
2. Is it a bad practice to use LIMIT in cases like this - although it shows much better performance?
3. Should I add a Primary key for the file id and user id? As I need to do for both as it is partitioned based on user id

*Using: Postgres 14*

Comment: You can't have a table partitioned the way you describe with the primary key you describe.

Comment: sorry, updated my question. There's no primary key indeed. Would adding PK optimize the query?

Comment: Please show the SQL statements to create your table and the indexes, as well as the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for your first query.